# GEE Python analysis over multiple features exported to dataframe

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am analysing some ERA5 wind data with Google Earth Engine in Python to extract the mean wind speed at a number of locations (buffers around points).

I have successfully done this for a single location and extracted the data to a dataframe.  But I have been trying to update the code to run the analysis now over multiple locations in a feature collection with no success.  My latest attempt is with nested map functions when I use reduceRegion to map over features then over image collection.  It gives the error

> Image collection object is not callable

What is wrong?

Latest code version below:

```
ERA5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/MONTHLY")

#Define start and end periods
start_period = ee.Date('2018-01-01')
end_period = ee.Date('2022-01-01')

#filter dataset to start and end period
ERA5 = ERA5.filter(ee.Filter.date(start_period, end_period))

#Calculate wind speed as a windspeed band
def windspeed(image):
  wind_10m = image.expression('sqrt(u**2 + v**2)', {
    'u': image.select('u_component_of_wind_10m'),
    'v': image.select('v_component_of_wind_10m')
  }).rename('windspeed')
  time = image.get('system:time_start')
  return wind_10m.set('system:time_start', time)

ERA5windspeed = ERA5.map(windspeed)

#Calculate mean wind speed for geometry per image

#import csv and convert to feature collection
sg_fc = feature2ee('sg_csv.csv')

#give geometry to feature collection
sg_fc_geo = sg_fc.geometry()

#add a buffer around each point in feature collection
def addBuffer(feature):
    return feature.buffer(10000)

#map function over each feature
buffers = sg_fc.map(addBuffer)

#reduce over area of interest to calculate average
def mean_speed(image):
    meanDict = image.select('windspeed').reduceRegion(
        reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(),
        geometry = buffers,
        scale = 27830,
  )
    return image.set(meanDict)

#map function
ERA5meanspeed = buffers.map(ERA5windspeed.map(mean_speed))
#**this creates an error saying Image Collection object is not callable

#Export data into a dataframe
#convert bands into arrays
time = ERA5meanspeed.aggregate_array('system:index').getInfo()
windspeed = ERA5meanspeed.aggregate_array('windspeed').getInfo()
#combine arrays into dataframe
windspeed_out = pd.DataFrame ({'time':time,'windspeed':windspeed})
#add location in for reference to which site
windspeed_out['x'] = list(geometry.getInfo().values())[1][0]
windspeed_out['y'] = list(geometry.getInfo().values())[1][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the calculated object `ERA5windspeed.map(mean_speed)` is of type `ee.ImageCollection` and cannot be mapped over the `buffers` collection.

To obtain statistics from a collection of images at a collection of points, you can define a function that uses [ee.Image.reduceRegions](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reduceregions?hl=en) to generate a FeatureCollection for each image:

```js
// Copyright 2022 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

def mean_speed(image):
    meanFC = image.select('windspeed').reduceRegions(
        collection = buffers,
        reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(),
        scale = 27830,
    )
    return meanFC
```

and then map that function over the collection of images (`ERA5windspeed`) to create a collection of feature collections. Use [ee.FeatureCollection.flatten](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-flatten?hl=en) to convert into a simple feature collection:

```js
ERA5meanspeed = ERA5windspeed.map(mean_speed).flatten()
```